# Finding collocated data in ignite

Tags: ignite

I am trying to collocate data based on SQL given in this link https://ignite.apache.org/features/collocatedprocessing.html .

I have created 2 caches 'Country' and 'City' using following SQLs.

```
-- Cache Country
CREATE TABLE Country (
Code CHAR(3),
Name CHAR(52),
Continent CHAR(50),
Region CHAR(26),
SurfaceArea DECIMAL(10,2),
Population INT(11),
Capital INT(11),
PRIMARY KEY (Code)) WITH "template=partitioned, backups=1";

--Cache City
CREATE TABLE City (
ID INT(11),
Name CHAR(35),
CountryCode CHAR(3),
District CHAR(20),
Population INT(11),
PRIMARY KEY (ID, CountryCode)
) WITH "template=partitioned, backups=1, affinityKey=CountryCode";
```

I have inserted some sample records, for example :

```
insert into Country values('RU','Rusia','Rusia','Rusia',0.0,00,0);
insert into Country values('IND','India','Asia','Asia',0.0,00,0);


insert into City values(101,'Mumbai','IND','NA',00);
insert into City values(102,'Moscow','RU','NA',00);
```

I have started 2 ignite(on different machines) node to collocate data on different nodes. After finding records presents on node 0 through visor

```
cache -scan -c=@c0 -id8=@n0
```

I can see both cities Mumbai and Moscow are present on node 0 (n0) as well as on node 1. I was expecting that cities of India will be collocated on node 0 and cities of Rusia will collocated on node 1 but not both on the same node.

My questions are :

1. I am doing anything wrong while collcating the data .
2. Running visor cache -scan command is correct way to find collocated data on nodes ?
3. If this is not correct way then, how can we find which data is collocated on node 0 and node 1 ?
4. Let's say data is collocated on node 0 (cities of India) and node 1 (cities on Rusia) . What will happen if one of the node will be disconnected from cluster ? Will there be a data loss ? After restarting the node, Will data be collocated again ?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and Visor will not be running local scan queries, so any node will return all data that is present in cluster.

So you can only check data collocation with code.

When you have backups, data will be failed over and there will be no data loss. When you add node back data will be rebalanced to it and backup restored.

Comment: I tried with collocated=true still it is giving all the cities.

Comment: Could you please give me a code for printing data from node 0 or node 1 ? Unfortunately, there is no documentation of this .

Comment: If it works with collocated=true (and JOIN) then you probably configured it correctly :)

Comment: You're not really supposed to consider whether data is on node 0 or node 1, it should be transparent and most operations will go where data is across cluster.

Comment: Let me rephrase my sentence, " I tried with collocated=true still it is giving all the cities." It means it is not showing me keys which are store only on node 0 or node 1 . It is showing all keys. Means it is not working.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to show all entries. As a rule you are supposed to be talking to whole cluster. You can still try `local=true`.

Comment: Are you sure local=true will work . I am trying to set local=true like this   `bin\sqlline.bat --verbose=true -u jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/;schema=PUBLIC;local=true` . I can connect to cluster but unable to fire SQL queries . After firing SQL query, I am getting exception Failed to set schema for DB connection . Can you tell me how to set local=true ?

Comment: Try `jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/?schema=PUBLIC&local=true`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunately, this is also showing all records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189887/discussion-between-nilkha-and-alamar).

Comment: Can you add more nodes? With backups=1 you will have all entries on all nodes.

Comment: @NilKha, you have just 2 nodes in your cluster with backups set to 1. It means that each node will store a full copy of the data and you'll always get a complete result set. Start the third node to see the difference.

Comment: I have removed local/collocated flags since they don't work.